# Synergy freezes while Microsoft Outlook busy

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, synergy

I have noticed that Synergy freezes temporarily while MS Outlook is busy accessing it's remote server.

I suspect that Outlook is hogging the network connection in some way?

To define "freeze" I cannot mouse over to my Ubuntu client, and also the multiple desktops on Windows then see that edge as a hard edge and flip desktops (normally that edge mouses over).

THis seems to persist while MS Outlook dhows an hourglass if I mouse over it.

The freeze then unfreezes when the hourglass disappears.

This is a pain because I'd rather be working on something on the Ubuntu machine while my windoze box catches up!

Any workaround suggestions appreciated.

I've noticed this both on XP and Win-7. And on outlook 2010 and whatever I was using before, probably 2007.

Comment: Anything wrong with making the Ubuntu box the server? Alternatively, check task manager when outlook hangs and see if there's a resource (CPU/Disk/internet) that becomes under heavy load during that time period

Comment: Does Synergy disconnect at this time or does it just hang up?

Also, are you using any security suite that will do a real-time scan on your E-Mail data which would cause CPU loading making Synergy slow down?

Answer (score 5):

These steps should fix this for you

1. On the Synergy server and select **Configure Server**
2. Go to **Advanced Server Settings**
3. In the top right **Options** section, check **Don't take foreground window on Windows servers**
4. Click **OK**
5. Apply the new config

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer as it does not actually answer anything

Comment: @Blaine He fixed it!

Comment: Yup! Looks like a great answer now